# Submit multiple forms with one request

Tags: forms, cakephp-3.x

I have two forms in the same view, each form is from a different entity/model.

I want to submit them with a single request, if possible the data should go to the corresponding controller + action.

How can this be accomplished?

**Edit:**

I want to edit entity B, that belongs to entity A, in entity's A form.

A has many B.

Comment: Smells a little [**xy-ish**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me... I don't think anyone here will be able to help you without you providing further information, starting with the reason for having the need for two forms in the first place. Sounds like a weird solution to a problem that you should have actually asked about.

Comment: @ndm While I'm editing  entity A, i want to be able to, at the same time(in the same view), edit entity B that belongs to entity A. As in "A has many B".

Comment: you have to create just one form. The manual explains how to create inputs for associated data [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-inputs-for-associated-data) and how to save associated data in you controller [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-request-data-into-entities)

Comment: @arilia thanks for your help, it looks like that is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@arilia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2776508/arilia) suggested, I went trough the manual.

First I associated the tables adding this to BTable

```
$this->belongsTo('A', [
        'foreignKey' => 'auto_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
```

and this to ATable

```
$this->hasMany('B');
```

In AController after this

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
```

I added this for the 'add' action,

```
$a= $this->A->patchEntity($a, $this->request->data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'B'
                ]
            ]);
```

In the edit action I did the same steps as above, plus this right after the function signature:

```
$a= $this->A->get($id, [
            'contain' => ['B']
        ]);
```

It solved the problem, since now I can edit associated entities with just one form.

Thanks [@arilia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2776508/arilia)